# Isn't it possible to configure logging INSIDE the application when using jboss AS 7.1.1.Final?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I read a lot but I couldn't figure out how I could specify for example the log level for specific classes.

Only way I could figure out was in the `standalone.xml` but why should I configure some application specific setting very general in the server? This complicates the deployment process unnecessary.

Isn't it somehow possible to **define** the specific **log level** and the **output files** somewhere **inside the war** *without touching the server*?

Btw. it doesn't matter if `log4j` or commons-logging or `slf4j` or whatever is used.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. Either you use server logging or application logging you need to write the configuration.

Comment: ?? I just want to bring the logs **of my application** to a specific log file.

Comment: I put logging.properties, commons-logging.properties, log4j.properties, (and some others which I forgot) in all possible folder (war-root, classpath, WEB-INF, ...). I also tried to load the config manually but this was also not successful. Because of missing documentation just a try and error with everything from the web.
But is it really important what I did? Isn't there a clear explanation how to configure out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `logging.properties` file or a log4j configuration file in your deployment will work in [JBoss EAP 6.x](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) and [WildFly](http://wildfly.org) (formerly JBoss AS). Note though that a log4j configuration would only work if you use log4j for your logging facade.

That said I agree with [Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830926/isnt-it-possible-to-configure-logging-inside-the-application-when-using-jboss-a#19831014) that this should probably be done in the server configuration. I would also encourage you to use the CLI or web interface rather than editing the raw XML as well. You can get some more information on the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+To).

Comment: Ok thx a lot. But just to make 100% sure. You mentioned EAP6.x and WildFly. So it isn't possible in 7.1.1.Final, right?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for not providing a direct answer, but consider this: the application being in charge of logging levels is a bad idea most of the time as this is something an AS admin should be able to change at any time. For example, the point of the DEBUG or TRACE log levels is to be able to place a lot of such statements in the code without hurting the production server's performance. However, once a bug is detected, you want to be able to lower the logging level *without rebuilding the application*. This should be a purely administrative task.

On the other hand, I do recognize the need to at least have a decent starting point for the logging configuration and I don't know of any architecture which would allow the application to provide defaults which are overridable by the server configuration.

Comment: How this relate to JBoss7  logging mechanism?

Comment: Such that it gives the rationale for configuring the logging in Jboss AS 7's `standalone.xml`, as opposed to a file contained in the deployed WAR/EAR.

Comment: Please teach me then, how is it wrong? You aren't helping either OP or me with your approach to this question.